# Using more then 1 item for a .click()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is this possible?

Code:

```
$('#goRightBtn').click(function() {
        Random code here
};
```

I have a button, when you click that button (goRightBtn) it will do all of the functions and whatnot inside that code up there. But I also have another button that will do the exact same thing (don't ask why.. Just need it!) How do I make it so that I can somehow make that code work when either one of the btns are selected..

Would something like

```
$('#goRightBtn','#secondBtn').click(function() {
        ///Random code here
};
```

work?

Please help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#goRightBtn, #secondBtn').click(function() {}
```

If you specify a second argument, that means you are specifying the **context**. Otherwise just put the ids in your initial argument's string like above.

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 2):

The following should work (a comma wrapping them)

```
$('#goRightBtn, #secondBtn').click(function() {
        ///Random code here
};
```

Or you can use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method also:

```
$('#goRightBtn').add('#secondBtn').click(function() {
        ///Random code here
};
```

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yeah spotted that before your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Almost had it right :) It's like this (called a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)):

```
$('#goRightBtn, #secondBtn').click(function() {
  ///Random code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EUyaf/)

```
$('#goRightBtn, #secondBtn').click(function() { 
        alert('test');
});
```

Comment: You should post code in the answer as well not just a demo (though something this simple doesn't need one, IMO).  If your demo site goes offline for any reason, the answer becomes useless :)